Creating an array at specific address with predefined size
I want to create an array at specific address with fixed size to access some physical memory in an embedded system using RISC-V. I have already used pointers to access memory regions, like
volatile int* mem1 = (volatile int*) SOME_ADDRESS ; 
mem1[0] = 1;

However, as I am accessing memory that is used also by core for its own local data I want it to avoid using that region of memory without modifying any linker script or startup code.
I tried to use malloc, but that does not seem to be supported in the setup that I have.
Is there a way in C code to make this work?

In Standard C? There is no way. In POSIX? mmap() might be an option.

This is baremetal, not possible to use that

"as I am accessing memory that is used also by core for its own local data" What do you mean with that, a RTOS?

Code contains other static variables that use this memory;  as I do not know the address of these variables I am worried that my buffer at SOME_ADDRESS could override their values.

If you consider malloc (if it was available) to be an option, then you don't seem to have a strict requirement about the specific address. What exactly do you want to do and why? If you don't want to interfere with other code parts, you could just create a real array and let the linker do its job.

If you want to make sure you don't use memory that is used by other parts of your program, either create an explicit array and let the compiler and linker handle its allocation; Or modify the linker script to put your data on a specific location.

@Gerhardh -> my use of malloc was actually wrong, as it returns the address and overrides the address that I defined.
It seems like my only option is to modify the linker script

"However, as I am accessing memory that is used also by core for its own local data" ?????? How can it be? How core can use any memory without program control?

You cannot align your memory usage with other parts of the code, without actually aligning it. Just randomly pick some address won't work as you already know. Tell the linker who is supposed to use what memory.

I want it to avoid ... modifying any linker script. Why? That is the most obvious way of doing it. A pointer as you showed in your example is also fine.

You should be able to create a global symbol denoting the address in the linker script, and declare it as an external array in the C code.

Declaring a variable at an absolute address depends on a compiler being used. Which compiler you are using ?
